# My device doesn't recognize my Arduino

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I'm planing to use the ESP8266 to create a web server as a start. My set up is: Arduino nano- Esp8266- Logic level converter  as shown in the diagram.
 [image: Diagram of ESP8266 connected to Arduino nano Using Circuito example]
After I connected everything my device doesn’t recognize the Arudion’s USB serial port, but when I disconnect everything from the breadboard and connect the Arduino alone it show up as COM3 and when I put the circuit back again and hock up the USB to my device it no longer show up.
I’m having the issue on both win 10 and mac.
Whenever I connected the usb cable to my computer the ESP8266 flashes a light for ones.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why doesn't my device recognize the Arduino when the ESP8266 is connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nano cannot power the ESP8266. It has an absolute maximum limit of about 50mA from the 3.3V pin, since it is provided by the USB interface chip. By drawing too much current (the ESP8266 needs hundreds of mA) the USB chip stops functioning.

You need an external 3.3V regulator to power the ESP8266.

Comment: I will try using an external source. but both the 5v and 3v are Connected to the chip doesn't that provide enough?

Comment: @Jacob No. You need at least 350mA but you only have 50mA. You need lots lots more power.